# Linux Regular Expression

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working with shell scripting in Linux. I want to check if the value of `MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE` is numeric or not. My code is like this:

```
MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE = "50"

expr="*[0-9]*"

if test -z "$MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE";
then
    echo "MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE variable is missing or not initiated"
else
    if [ "$MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE" != $expr ]
    then
        echo "$MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE is not a valid value"
    fi
fi
```

I want to match the value of `MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE` with my expr. Please help.

Comment: Shell script syntax is not a feature of the kernel, and Bash is portable to numerous Unix platforms as well as Windows, so there isn't really anything "Linux" in your question.

Comment: Your definition of numeric is restricted to "whole numbers" only ?

Answer (score 4):

For POSIX compatibility, look at `case`. I also find it more elegant than the corresponding `if` construct, but the syntax may seem a bit odd when you first see it.

```
case $MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE in
  '' ) echo "empty" >&2 ;;
  *[!0-9]* ) echo "not a number" >&2 ;;
esac
```

By the way, notice the redirection of error messages to standard error with `>&2`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `expr` will match anything that contains *any* digits; it's better to check if it contains *only* digits, or conversely, to check if it contains any *non*-digits. To do that, you can write:

```
if ! [[ "$MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE" ]] ; then
    echo "MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE is blank or uninitialized" >&2
elif [[ "$MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE" == *[^0-9]* ]] ; then
    echo "$MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE is not a valid value" >&2
fi
```

Also, note that you would initialize `MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE` by writing e.g. `MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE=50` (no spaces), not `MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE = 50`. The latter tries to run a program called `MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE` with the arguments `=` and `50`.

Comment: is there another way to match the value with a numeric regular expression? "$MAX_ARCHIVE_AGE" == *[^0-9]* seems not working.

Comment: @SciasTwentyThree: Sure there are other ways, but this way works fine. (I've tested it.) If the most you can get from it is "seems not working", then it's not clear to me what other ways you'll have better luck with . . .